# Why can I set a property value although Animation.FillBehavior is set to HoldEnd

Tags: wpf, silverlight, animation

I came across a different behaviour in Silverlight and WPF when an animated property values is held ("filled") after the animation has ended. The Remarks section in the documentation of the [FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
property says

> The filling behavior can create the illusion that a property is
>   unsettable at runtime if you are not careful about stopping unintended
>   animations. Attempting to change the animated value coming from a
>   filling animation in code will appear to have no effect until the
>   filling animation is stopped.

However, in Silverlight this seems not to be true. In the small example below I animate the `Opacity` of a filled `Rectangle` to zero when the "Fade Out" button is clicked. Although the animation's `FillBehavior` is set to `HoldEnd`, resetting the Opacity to 1 in the "Reset" button click handler works and the Button reappears. If I do the same in a WPF application it behaves as expected, namely clicking the "Reset" button has no visual effect.

My question is, has anybody else observed this behavior? Is it perhaps a bug in Silverlight, or am I missing something?

I'm using Silverlight 5 and WPF 4.5 here.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Rectangle Name="rect" Width="200" Height="100" Fill="DarkGreen"/>
    <Button Content="Fade Out" Click="FadeOutButtonClick"/>
    <Button Content="Reset" Click="ResetButtonClick"/>
</StackPanel>
```

-

```
private void FadeOutButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = 0d,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd
    };

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, rect);

    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    storyboard.Begin();
}

private void ResetButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rect.Opacity = 1d;
}
```

Comment: Seems like it may well be a bug. Certainly does not align with the precedence order specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265148(v=vs.95).aspx#listing). Can you try moving the storyboard local variable to a member variable of the class, just to make sure it isn't being GC'd and therefore stopped?

Comment: @KentBoogaart Good point, but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a reverse animation on the reset :

```
private void ResetButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            To = 1d,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd
        };

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, rect);

        var storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        storyboard.Begin();
```

Hope This will help.

Comment: I know, but that was not the question.

Comment: didn't realize, sorry about my mistake.